# std::weak_ptr: lock or shared_ptr constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

There seem to be two ways to temporarily grab ownership of the resource pointed to by a `weak_ptr`:

1. Use `lock()`
2. Pass the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` constructor

Both of these produce a `shared_ptr`, with the lock returning a `nullptr` in the case that the `weak_ptr` is empty and the `shared_ptr` constructor throwing an exception.

So the question is: when should one or the other be used?  Are there general guidelines or best practices related to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock

> Both this function and the constructor of std::shared_ptr may be used
>   to acquire temporary ownership of the managed object referred to by a
>   std::weak_ptr. The difference is that the constructor of
>   std::shared_ptr throws an exception when its std::weak_ptr argument is
>   empty, while std::weak_ptr::lock() constructs an empty
>   std::shared_ptr.

That leads me to believe that you pick which one to use based on whether you want an exception thrown or not.  The constructor can be used when it **must** work, whereas `lock` can be used when it's possible that it won't work and you can check.