# std::weak_ptr::lock and object destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I know that in a multi-threading environment it's not safe to check whether an object has been fully deleted by `std::shared_ptr<T>::use_count() == 0`, because the object's destructor may still be not completed.

But what about using `std::weak_ptr::lock()` instead?

```
if (weak_ptr.lock() == nullptr) {
    // The object's destructor is guaranteed to be completed?
}
```

Comment: No, `lock()` also tells you whether the object is still safe to use (the decision to destroy the object has not yet been made).  You don't even know that the destructor has *started* running, let alone completed.

Comment: The reason why `use_count() == 0` doesn't work is because it's only 0 if the shared pointer isn't managing an object. If you have a shared pointer to something then `use_count` will be at least 1. As soon as you reset the pointer you have no idea about the state of the object it used to point to.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way to know for sure that an object's destructor has completed, except maybe to monitor the allocator that manages that object's storage. If the storage becomes available, then the object's lifetime has completed ended already. But even if you put some sort of event signaling directly at the end of the destructor, you can't know if the calling theard has actually returned or not since signalling the event. It seems like a strange requirement in the first place. Can you share why you need this?

Comment: The standard is rather cryptic: "**[util.smartptr.shared]/5** Changes in `use_count()` do not reflect modifications that can introduce data races." I'm not sure how to read that. However, I believe any sane implementation of `~shared_ptr` would reduce `use_count` to zero first, and then destroy the underlying object, precisely so that it's impossible to obtain a soon-to-be-dangling pointer to the object that's half-way through destruction. `weak_ptr.lock() == nullptr` tells you that the last `shared_ptr` instance has already started its destruction, but not whether the object it held did.

Comment: If weak_ptr.lock() returns nullptr, that means that the object's lifetime has irrevocably expired, no more. The destructor may or may not have completed, but as the object's pointer is now unrecoverable (unless stored outside of a smart pointer previously) the only way of knowing about the destruction is if the destructor has some other side effect. Note that "destruction" is not necessarily the same as "my program now uses less memory", as the underlying allocator linked into it is likely holding on to freed memory in case more is needed later on, to minimise expensive system calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::weak\_ptr: lock or shared\_ptr constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139018/stdweak-ptr-lock-or-shared-ptr-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should all be equivalent:

```
weak_ptr.use_count() == 0
weak_ptr.lock() == nullptr
weak_ptr.expired()
```

They share the interpretation that the last managing `shared_ptr` has begun its destruction. They do not imply that the managed object has yet begun its destruction, nor that it has completed its destruction.